# gdb cannot break on watchpoint on character in string?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, watch

I am working on RP2040 Pico, and `gdb` connected via openocd and Picoprobe (note that the RP2040 has two cores, which `gdb` recognizes as two "threads").

I have previously tried gdb `watch` on global `uint8_t` variables and such on this platform, and it seems to break fine.

Now, I've got a problem, that a (global) string that I write with with:

```
snprintf(stringbuf, sizeof(stringbuf), "val: %3d", the_value)
```

... and I can confirm `the_value` does not change from value 100 in `gdb` - I can see that the character buffer of size 9 (i.e. string of size 8) at a certain point in time unexpectedly changes from `val: 100` to `val:   0`.

So, not having other things to debug by (again, `the_value` does not change from 100) - I tried to add a watchpoint on the 6-th (1-based, so index 5 zero-based) character, expecting it will break when the character changes from `1` to  , and the backtrace will reveal what has changes this character, and therefore string.

So, just to make sure I do not mess up with syntax, I tried to set a watchpoint directly on the address of the 6th character in this string, interpreted as a `char`:

```
(gdb) p stringbuf
$1 = "val:   0"
(gdb) p &stringbuf
$2 = (char (*)[9]) 0x20000618 <stringbuf>

(gdb) p &stringbuf[5]
$3 = 0x2000061d <stringbuf+4> "  0"
(gdb) p *(char*)0x2000061d
$4 = 32 ' '

(gdb) watch *(char*)0x2000061d
Hardware watchpoint 4: *(char*)0x2000061d
(gdb) info br
Num     Type           Disp Enb Address    What
4       hw watchpoint  keep y              *(char*)0x2000061d
(gdb) r
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: ...
```

The messages from `gdb` look all good - except that, the watchpoint NEVER breaks; even though I can do:

```
...
(Ctrl-C)
Thread 1 received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x10009588 in ...

(gdb) p *(char*)0x2000061d
$19 = 49 '1'
(gdb) c
Continuing.

( ... Ctrl-C)
Thread 1 received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x10008238 in ...
(gdb) p *(char*)0x2000061d
$20 = 32 ' '
```

... and I can see, that obiously the character at address 0x2000061d has indeed changed its value.

Am I doing anything wrong - and how can I add a watchpoint correctly on this memory address, so `gdb` breaks whenever this memory location changes value? Or maybe `gdb`, or the platform I use, does not support watchpoints on char variables, or something similar?

Comment: Have you tried using something like `watch -l stringbuf[5]` to create a memory watchpoint?

Comment: Thank you @Hasturkun - amazingly, that (the `watch -l`) seems to have worked here!